# Firefox + jQuery: On success not firing on ajax call with large amount of return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a page that posts to a site using jQuery's ajax function.
The response is a JSON object that contains a message and some other status codes as well as encoded HTML which is rendered to a div in the success callback.

This works fine for the most part, but, when using latest firefox (inc beta) the success callback never fires when the response is larger than around 1 Meg.

Is this a known issue and is there a workaround?

I have attempted to scrap the JSON object and send back straight html, but the same problem occurs. Firefox and jQuery 1.4 do not seem to like response's that are larger than average.

Thanks

UPDATE - more detail
I am using Firefox 3.6.13 and jQuery 1.4 together with asp.net MVC 2.
Data is returned using the Json method in MVC2. Partial Views are rendered to strings to make up the JSON. Bear in mind that I see the same behaviour when returning flat html.

I will hook up the onError callback and see if that gets called.

UPDATE 2
The Error callback is showing me that a 'parseerror' is occurring.

Comment: What exact versions of firefox / jQuery are we talking about? Are the error callbacks fireing? (try to use $.ajax instead of $.post and add success/error/complete handlers to debug)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll want to avoid encoded HTML. Pass back just the JSON data and use jquery templates instead (http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/).

Browsers do impose size limits on JSON and it is different across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I [stumbled upon](http://blog.m0sa.net/2011/02/jqueryvalidation-breaks-jquery-15-ajax.html) a similar error today, but I was using jQuery 1.5 and MVC3. The cause for the errors was jQuery.validation updating the applying  default AJAX settings to every ajax call, making the normal AJAX call a JSONP call. The parseerror was thrown because no JSONP callback could be found. Perhaps you are facing a similar problem.